# I can't operate an int with a float

Tags: python

I have to make a code that calculates the molar mass of a chemical compound, I already got to an idea I think it´s quite correct, here is the code:

```
import re
import chemistry


def mol_weigth(formula):
    result = 0
    pattern = ("([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)(\\d{0,2})")   #pattern of a chemical compound

    for match in re.finditer(pattern, formula):
        if match.group(2) == 0:
            atoms = 1.00
        else:
            atoms = match.group(2)
        result += atoms * chemistry.atom_weight(match.group(1))

    return result
```

My problem is in line 14 #"""result += atoms * chemistry.atom_weight(match.group(1))""" as it gives the error: **"can´t multiply sequence by non-int of type "float"**
I tried to fix it by changing line 13 #atoms = match.group(2) by this:

```
atoms = match.group(2)
atoms = float(atoms)
```

This to try to turn the number of atoms into float, by I get the same error, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Your function is trying to do too much. You have two completely separate tasks here: parsing a formula into is constituent atoms or molecules, then finding the total weight of those atoms/molecules. Each should be its own function.

Answer (score 1):

`match.group(2)` returns `string` not `int`.

And when nothing is found, it returns an empty string `''` not `0`.

```
import re
import chemistry


def mol_weigth(formula):
    result = 0
    pattern = ("([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)(\\d{0,2})")   #pattern of a chemical compound

    for match in re.finditer(pattern, formula):
        if match.group(2) == '': # empty string when nothing is found
            atoms = 1.00
        else:
            atoms = int(match.group(2)) # string to int
        result += atoms * chemistry.atom_weight(match.group(1))

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the sequence by an integer, not a float. First of all, you need to set atoms to be `1`, instead of `1.00` which is a float. Then you also need to parse match.group(2) to be an integer. Try this:

```
import re
import chemistry


def mol_weigth(formula):
    result = 0
    pattern = ("([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)(\\d{0,2})")   #pattern of a chemical compound

    for match in re.finditer(pattern, formula):
        if match.group(2) == 0:
            atoms = 1
        else:
            atoms = int(match.group(2))
        result += atoms * chemistry.atom_weight(match.group(1))

    return result
```

Comment: If I do that it gives me a value error in line 13 #ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ""